# Brewing a braggot.

Tags: beer-styles, honey, techniques, recipe

How much honey do you need to put into a beer recipe before you can really call it a braggot?  I am sure the taste is largely subjective.
I want to brew a beer with 1/3 Honey, 1/3 2-row, 1/3 wheat.  I guess I could call that a braggot.

Comment: Not putting this as an actual answer, but here's the BJCP guideline: http://www.bjcp.org/2008styles/style26.php#1b

Comment: I think you should add it as an actual answer. The BJCP is the closest thing we have to an authority on what is admittedly a subjective subject.  Plus, I can't think of any other way of answering this question that isn't just farting in the wind.

Comment: @TinCoyote  I totally agree.  I think if I wanted to call a 1/3, 1/3 1/3 a braggot whose going to stop me right.  And if the beer tastes great..I mean braggot, then people will even be more inclined to agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a definitive answer to this question. My personal view would be that braggot is a mead made with malt, and not a beer made with honey. I'd say a mead is a fermented beverage with more than 50% of its sugars from honey, thus your brew would not fit the bill.

However, the [Mazer Cup mead competition](http://www.meadfest.org/mcic_entry_guidelines.htm) defines braggot as "Honeywine made with malt, must be fermented from at least 20% honey" so by that definition you are making braggot. I think that's the closest thing we have to an authoritative answer.